# MVVM WPF Windows app - Binding to custom property in template

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm having a binding problem, and I'm starting to think that there's something wrong with my approach to this problem.

I'm inside a Button style template, and I need to bind a DataTrigger to a custom property "BindingRef".

This code should change an Image named btnImage to "DisabledImage" when the custom property changes value.

Here's the code in the template:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(helper:BindingHelper.BindingRef), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static helper:StatusEnum.Disabled}">
     <Setter TargetName="btnImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=(helper:ImageLoader.DisabledImage)}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I know, a lot of things happening there.
However everything works if instead of "(helper:BindingHelper.BindingRef)" I set a fixed binding source.

Here's BindingHelper:

```
public static class BindingHelper
{
    public static string GetBindingRef(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (string)target.GetValue(BindingRefProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBindingRef(DependencyObject target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(BindingRefProperty,value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingRefProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindingRef",
                                            typeof(string),
                                            typeof(BindingHelper),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(null));
   
}
```

and inside the View:

```
<Button ...
     helper:ImageLoader.DisabledImage="/Resources/disabled.png"
     Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" 
     Command="{Binding btnCommand}" 
     helper:BindingHelper.BindingRef="MyProperty" />
```

This compiles and I get no errors, but it's not working.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't blame me, I know that the best solution is to adapt the DataContext and directly use one of its properties.
I'm just wondering if this alternative way could work.

Comment: `Value="{x:Static helper:StatusEnum.Disabled}` seems to indicate that the type of the BindingRef property should be an enum, not string. Besides that, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. It has no effect at all.